# In Django, how to bind the dropdown list with data from another table using foreign key?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

```
model.py

class LabTable(models.Model):
    LabNo = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Pid = models.IntegerField()
    Weight = models.IntegerField()
    DoctorId = models.ForeignKey(DoctorTable,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Date = models.DateField()
    Category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    PatientType = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Amount = models.IntegerField()

class DoctorTable(models.Model):
 DoctorId = models.AtuoField(primary_key = True) 
DoctorName = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
 Department = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

1.Here, I have created the lab model and a foreign key with doctor table. I want to use doctor table to present data in dropdown.

Comment: It's not really clear *what* you want to do. My guess is that you are looking for a package like [**`django-select2`**](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @WillemVanOnsem i have tried this but it didn't work for me. Actually i am looking for something where i can save doctorId in lab table and want to display doctorName against that doctorId in dropdownList and same incase of edit/update the record.

Comment: You already store the doctor id in the Labtable, that is what the `ForeignKey` is doing.

Comment: Yes, but now problem is that i am getting data as object in dropdown where i have only need doctorName

Comment: can you share the `DoctorTable` model?

Comment: class DoctorTable(models.Model):
 DoctorId = models.AtuoField(primary_key = True)
 DoctorName = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
 Department = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

Comment: please [edit] the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify how to show a `DoctorTable` model object by implementing the `__str__` method for that model, so:

```
class DoctorTable(models.Model):
    DoctorId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    DoctorName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Department = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.DoctorName
```

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `doctor_name` instead of <s>`DoctorName`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Models normally have no `Table` suffix. A model is not a table, it is stored in a relational database as a table, but even then it has extra logic like validators, managers, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I Will try this.